# Drone2Map Export as Package Project

Tags: map-package, drone2map

In Drone2Map, is there any way to export a Drone2Map Project File as a Package Project, like in ArcGIS Pro? I want to share my project as a whole with people but the only way I can see how to do it is through web maps or layers.